# Creating c ++ library: lite version vs full version

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, static, g++

I created a C++ library and would like to provide a set of methods in the lite version and a complement in the full version. I could use inheritance, but I would like to keep the same name as the class that will be instantiated. I would like to use the same class to facilitate compatibility (access type migration) and code maintenance.

Initially, I had thought of using something like build directives to make "invisible" methods, but I realized that users could activate these directives.

Something like:

```
class A
{
   public:
      A();
      void read();

      #ifdef MYTAG
      void write();    
      #endif
};
```

The problem with this approach is that if the developer knows MYTAG he can use the methods of the full version. It would also be necessary to remove the directive from the header files.

Does anyone suggest any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If someone has access to the source no restrictions you try and put in place will do anything more than irritate the user as they go though and remove them

Comment: Ideally, it should be transparent to users who do not have that access. They wouldn't even know about these methods.. This would only be to avoid two different classes (Class ALite / AFull).

Comment: To use your library uses must have access to the headers at least. If you do not want to have to compile all the binaries yourself they will also need access to the source. Therefore short of distributing two copies of the library there is no way to do this, you should also not _try_ to do this as there is really no point